# How do I check if a TDateEdit is left blank by the user?

Tags: datepicker, freepascal, lazarus

I'm using the TDateEdit control on Lazarus and I have set the date format to DMY. So I see some characters for the user like `'__/__/____'` in the date input box.

My concern is that I don't want the user to leave this field blank so I'm trying the following code as a test:

```
  if dtWeekEndingDate.Date = 0 Then
     begin
       Errors := true;
       showmessage ('blank');
     end;
```

The code seems to do what I want but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Is the above method the right way to check for an unset or unentered date? I used the **.Text** property but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you can consider 0 (zero=30.12.1899 00:00) as a 'blank' date in your application. You can see this simply with outputing 'empty' TDateEdit control:

```
ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('DD MM YYYY hh:nn',DateEdit1.Date));
```

If this date is a valid and posible entry in your case then use onChange event to set boolean that something is entered or directly check and process another property of TDateEdit control:

```
DateEdit1.Text
```

Of course you can use some nice components allready handling this kind of 'problem' as:
[ZVDateTimeControls](http://wiki.freepascal.org/ZVDateTimeControls_Package#NullInputAllowed%3a_Boolean)

Comment: You've got a point there. I don't really need that date (1899) but it means that checking the Date for 0 is not a good idea. Instead I think like you said it's better to check against the Text property. And I'm not keen on using additional controls for two reasons. First, licensing and second code size. As it is, I'm fighting to keep the code footprint small :/